# Define $Y(E,f)=\{\int_E \phi dm: 0\le \phi \le f, \phi \; \text{is simple}\}$. Show that the set $Y(E,f)$ is always an interval.

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ be a nonnegative measurable function and $E\in \mathcal{M}$, where $\mathcal{M}$ is the sigma algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets of $\mathbb{R}$. Define $Y(E,f)=\{\int_E \phi dm: 0\le \phi \le f, \phi \; \text{is simple}\}$. Show that the set $Y(E,f)$ is always of the form $[0,x]$ or $[0,x)$, where the value $x=\infty$ is allowed.

In the text it is just said that "clearly" $Y(E,f)$ is always of the form $[0,x]$ or $[0,x)$, however, I cannot think of a way to show this apparently obvious fact. How can I show this? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: If $\phi\in Y(E,f)$ and $\lambda\in[0,1)$, then $\lambda\phi\in Y(E,f)$, and $\int(\lambda\phi)\,dm<\int\phi\,dm$ (unless the latter is $0$).

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $0\le\phi\le f$, then $0\le c\phi\le f$ for any $c\in[0,1]$. Since $\int_E c\phi\,dm=c\int_E\phi\,dm$ you obtain all values between $0$ and $\int_E\phi\,dm$ for each $\phi$, and thus all values between $0$ and $Y(E,f)$.